# How to integrate facebook with my weebly website

Tags: facebook, authentication, registration

I have a website developed on weebly. I want to integrate my website with facebook registration and login so that members can login on my site through their facebook login information. Weebly gives me an option to have a custom html through which i can get a code to allow the facebook login onto my website

Comment: Create a FB app at developers.facebook.com . This gives you an app_id (number). Download the FB js-sdk and/or php-sdk.  Add the FB login button to your site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

And the Registration plugin:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

Then write some backend code (php) that checks if the user is logged in and writes to your database. 
Not sure if Weebly gives you access to the backend webserver (eg. php).

Answer (score 0):

Weebly does not provide you access to PHP , the only option you have is javascript, i have written a working script based on js-sdk specially for weebly websites, this script will allow users to login via facebook and auto-fill up the sign up form with their facebook data.